# Combine columns from different files

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have two text files that have these structures:

**File 1**

```
Column1:Column2
Column1:Column2
...
```

**File 2**

```
Column3
Column3
...
```

I would like to create a file that has this file structure:

```
Column1:Column3
Column1:Column3
...
```

Open to any suggestions, but it would be nice if the solution can be done from a Bash shell, or sed / awk / perl / *etc*...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cut -d: -f1 "File 1" | paste -d: - "File 2"
```

This cuts field 1 from File 1 (delimited by a colon) and pastes it with the only column in File 2, separating the output fields with a colon.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an awk solution. It assumes file1 and file2 have an equal number of lines.

```
awk -F : '{ printf "%s:",$1; getline < "file2"; print }' < file1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since a pure bash implementation hasn't been suggested, also assuming an equal number of lines (bash v4 only):

```
mapfile -t file2 < file2

index=0
while IFS=: read -r column1 _; do
        echo "$column1:${file2[index]}"
        ((index++))
done < file1
```

bash v3:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' file2 < file2

index=0
while IFS=: read -r column1 _; do
        echo "$column1:${file2[index]}"
        ((index++))
done < file1
```